# SQL summing a substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that would take the first letter of the location(as the aisle) and sum the capacity for just that letter

Another issue with it is i'm joining a table where each location lists multiple times for each piece of stock in that location.

---

EDIT...
ok so seems i need to sum the capacity on distinct locations? (not distinct capacity)

### SQL so far

```
SELECT

SUBSTRING(table_loc.Location,1,1) as 'Aisle',

SUM(table_loc.Capacity) as 'Aisle Capacity',

SUM(table_stock.LocationQTY) as 'Units in aisle'

FROM   table_loc 

INNER JOIN table_stock

ON table_loc.Location = table_stock.Location

GROUP BY SUBSTRING(table_loc.Location,1,1)
```

---

### table_loc

```
Location     Capacity

A001           3

A002           2

B001           2

B002           2
```

---

### table_stock

```
 Item    Location   LocationQTY

 ShirtA     A001           1

 ShirtB     A001           1 

 PantsA     A002           1   

 PantsB     A002           1 

 WidgetA    B001           1  

 WidgetB    B001           1  

 HatA       B002           1  

 HatB       B002           1
```

---

### (current)Results

currently my results are getting multiplied by each "item" in the location

```
Location    Capacity     LocationQTY

   A            13           8

   B            8            8
```

---

### (desired)Results

```
Location    Capacity     LocationQTY

   A            5             4

   B            4             4
```

Hope i didn't over confuse this.

Thanks again

Comment: What are using? mysql or sql server? you can't have both

Comment: Is your example table both tables combined?  Can you show the tables separated?

Comment: updated to show the two tables.

Comment: @JasonT I've updated my answer and checked it.  Seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by Aisle.

**EDIT**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ec44/2

Because you need to sum a column in the 2nd table, you'll need to do the following:

```
Select Left(table_loc.Location, 1) As Aisle, Sum(table_loc.Capacity) As Aisle_Capacity, table_stock.Units_In_Aisle
From table_loc
Inner Join (
    Select Left(table_stock.Location, 1) As Aisle, Sum(table_stock.LocationQTY) As Units_In_Aisle
    From table_stock
    Group By Aisle) As table_stock On (Left(table_loc.Location, 1) = table_stock.Aisle)
Group By Aisle
```

Comment: @destination-data True, I didn't pay close enough attention to their original query.  Updated the query.

Comment: You cannot combined sum with distinct.

Comment: I just tried it.  @DStanley you are 100% right.  I stand corrected.  A distinct sum here would equal 15.  A non-distinct would equal 25.

Comment: I guess in this case, though, they do not want distinct capacities anyway, according to what the expected output was to be.

Comment: If i remove the sum(distinct) it works...so far!... but when I bring in the stock table, everything gets multiplied. so for aisle A the results are 205 (A001 5 times + A002 10 time + A003 10 times). If i keep the sum(distinct)  my results are A 15 and B 22

Comment: @JTOM It sounds like it is still a "Group By" issue.  Can you show both tables and what fields you are joining them with?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use `left`.  Second, no `distinct` is necessary:

```
SELECT LEFT(table.Location, 1) as Aisle,
       SUM(table.Capacity) as AisleCapacity
FROM t
GROUP BY LEFT(table.Location, 1);
```

Note:  don't use single quotes for column aliases.  This is likely to cause confusion in the future.  Most column aliases don't need to be escaped.  If you want to use strange characters such as spaces in names, then use the proper escape character for your database (backticks, double quotes, or square braces).